# how to access NSMutablearray in another UIViewcontroller?

Tags: ios5, nsmutablearray

I have  a `NSMutable` array defined in `NSObject` class like this

`NSMutableArray *allbilltypeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dir_AddBillName"]];`

Now I want to get element one by one from this `NSMutablearray` in another view controller.How can I do this in another view controller.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to declare the NSMutableArray as a property of its containing class in the header file, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allbilltypeArray;
```

You should then synthesise the property in the implementation file.

Now if you declare an instance of the class that contains the array in another view controller like so (or similar):

```
ContainingClass *class = [[ContainingClass alloc] init];
```

you will be able to access a particular element in the array by doing something like:

```
Object *o = [class.allbilltypeArray objectAtIndex: i];
```

Or loop through them all like so:

```
for (Object *o in class.allbilltypeArray) {
      //Do something with object
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tryed this,after define as a property and synthesizing,when I try to give allbilltypeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dir_AddBillName"]];in my database retriew method in .m file it gives an error `instance variable "allbilltypeArray"accessed in class method` what is the reason for this.

Comment: First I want to assign the array in same class and then want to use in another viewcontroller

Comment: This may help:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/43169-instance-variable-accessed-in-class-method.html